# Using AwesomeCV is it possible to remove whitespace left between Title and the items?

Tags: latex

Using the cv entry code below I am left with the whitespace in between Title (Quantitative Techniques Research) and the items (Investigated...). This is due to Role being empty as i often do not require it.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\begin{document}
\cvsection{Projects}

\begin{cventries}
\cventry
    {}% Role - Empty
    {Title}
    % Event
    {Everywhere} % Location
    {Current} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Item 1}
        \item{Item 2}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
```

[image: Whitespace between Title and Items where Role is.]

There was recently a PR to remove the whitespace when position 5 is left empty, updating the cventry code, as shown below

```
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4}}
    \ifempty{#5}{}{\\\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
\end{document}
```

The ifempty condition on the second last line removes the whitespace if positions is left empty. I have tried to recreate this line for ifempty{#1} but with little success. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of these code fragments

Comment: Have added begin and \end{cventries}. Using cvawesome this is reproducible.

Comment: Do you have the link to the PR ? I am curious to see if this was ever merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\ifempty{#1}{\vskip-1.2\baselineskip}{}\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\begin{document}
\cvsection{Projects}

\begin{cventries}
\cventry
    {}% Role - Empty
    {Title}
    % Event
    {Everywhere} % Location
    {Current} % Date(s)
    {%
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Item 1}
        \item{Item 2}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
\cventry
    {Duck}% Role - Empty
    {Title}
    % Event
    {Everywhere} % Location
    {Current} % Date(s)
    {%
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Item 1}
        \item{Item 2}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

[image]